# Visual Studio indents for shorthand initialisation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I write a class' constructor and use shorthand initializations like this:

```
A(int x, int y) :
    position(x, y),
    image(nullptr) {
}
```

Visual studio formats it like this:

```
A(int x, int y) :
position(x, y),
    image(nullptr) {
}
```

Is there any option in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 to format the indents correctly?

Comment: Where is the "shorthand" initialization? As far as I can tell, you've written it out in full.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As far as I know they're called like that, it's the part between the `:` and `{`.

Comment: Calling that a "shorthand" implies that there is a longer or more verbose alternative, which is not true: this is the _only_ member initialization syntax (well, discounting C++11 inline initialisers). Perhaps you consider `A(int x, int y) { position = Vec2D(x, y); image = nullptr; }` to be a "longhand initialization", but in fact this is no initialisation at all! Only assignments after-the-fact.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's shorter and faster than writing `position = Vec2D(x, y);` within the method. It's how I've been thought to call them at school.

Comment: You were taught wrong. `position = Vec2D(x, y)` is not initialization at all, and I've never heard anyone else use this erroneous "shorthand initialization" term to describe what is properly called _member initialization_. Sorry!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No need to say sorry, thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the broken "automatic indentation" and type the <kbd>TAB</kbd>s yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you, I found the option here: _Tools > Options... > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > Identification > Automatic Indentification on Tab_